# Schemas validity error : Element 'game': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml, xsd

I have checked the related questions and i have been looking around to solve this problem but i guess I wont find a remedy. Here is my code to my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<game xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="game.xsd">
<info>
    <name>"Mensch, aergere dich nicht!"</name>
    <description>"Mensch ärgere dich nicht ist ein Gesellschaftsspiel für zwei bis sechs Personen."
                <i>"Das Spielbrett ist in der Einzelausgabe doppelseitig bedruckt" 
                    <b> "sodass Mensch ärgere dich nicht für maximal sechs Spieler"</b>
                </i>
                <b>"auf der einen und maximal vier Spieler auf der anderen Seite spielbar ist."
                </b>    
     </description>
    <started>2012-09-24-06:00</started>
    <players number="2">
        <screenname player="1">"Onat Derebek"</screenname>
        <screenname player="2">"Kutay Derebek"</screenname>
    </players>
    <rounds>1</rounds>
    <winner player="1"></winner>
</info>
<moves> 
<!-- Erste figuren -->
    <roll player="1">6</roll>
    <piece player="1" nr="1" field="26"/>

    <roll player="2">6</roll>
    <piece player="2" nr="5" field="36"/>

    <roll player="1">6</roll>
    <piece player="1" nr="1" field="32"/>


</moves>
```

and here is the code to my xsd file

```
<element name="game">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="info" type="tns:infoType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="moves" type="tns:movesType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>


<complexType name="infoType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0">
        </element>
        <element name="description" type="tns:descriptionType"
            maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
        </element>
        <element name="started" type="dateTime" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0">
        </element>
        <element name="players" minOccurs="0">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="screenname" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4">
                        <complexType>
                            <simpleContent>
                                <extension base="string">
                                    <attribute name="player"
                                        type="tns:playerType" use="required">
                                    </attribute>
                                </extension>
                            </simpleContent>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                </sequence>

                <attribute name="number" type="tns:playerType" use="required"></attribute>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="rounds" type="int" minOccurs="0"></element>
        <element name="winner" minOccurs="0">
            <complexType>
                <attribute name="player" type="tns:playerType" use="required"></attribute>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="descriptionType" mixed="true">
    <choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
        <element name="i" type="tns:descriptionType"></element>
        <element name="b" type="tns:descriptionType"></element>
    </choice>
</complexType>


<complexType name="movesType">
    <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="roll" nillable="false">
            <complexType mixed="false">
                <simpleContent>
                    <extension base="tns:simpleIntType">
                        <attribute name="player" use="required">
                            <simpleType>
                                <restriction base="int">
                                    <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
                                    <maxInclusive value="4"></maxInclusive>
                                </restriction>
                            </simpleType>
                        </attribute>
                    </extension>
                </simpleContent>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="piece">
            <complexType>
                <attribute name="nr" use="required">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="int">
                            <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
                            <maxInclusive value="16"></maxInclusive>
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="player" use="required">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="int">
                            <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
                            <maxInclusive value="4"></maxInclusive>
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </attribute>
                <attribute name="field" use="required">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="int">
                            <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
                            <maxInclusive value="72"></maxInclusive>
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </attribute>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </choice>
</complexType>

<simpleType name="simpleIntType">
    <restriction base="int">
        <maxInclusive value="6"></maxInclusive>
        <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>


<simpleType name="playerType">
    <restriction base="int">
        <minInclusive value="1"></minInclusive>
        <maxInclusive value="4"></maxInclusive>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

I need to solve this problem in an hour because I have to upload for a college project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fond memories of playing "Mensch ärgere dich nicht" during childhood holidays in Germany, in fact, we brought a set home with us and it still comes out sometimes on visits to the parental home. It's similar to the game known in England as Ludo, but subtle differences in the rules mean that it works much better.

> I need to solve this problem in an hour

Then hopefully you have learnt a useful lesson about time management.

Clearly there is an element declaration for the root element (game). You haven't shown us the xs:schema element of your schema document, so there could be a problem with namespaces; but I think a more likely explanation is that you have invoked the schema validator incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that in your XSD you are using `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` as your default namespace, and so all the types are defined in that namespace, whereas your XML file does not use any namespace.

Try to associated `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` with a prefix (e.g. xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) and define your schema without a target namespace - it works fine for me in this way.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="game">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="info" type="infoType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
          <xs:element name="moves" type="movesType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


  <xs:complexType name="infoType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"
          minOccurs="0">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="description" type="descriptionType"
          maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="started" type="xs:dateTime" maxOccurs="1"
          minOccurs="0">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="players" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="screenname" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="player"
                        type="playerType" use="required">
                    </xs:attribute>
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>

          <xs:attribute name="number" type="playerType" use="required"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="rounds" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="winner" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="player" type="playerType" use="required"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="descriptionType" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="i" type="descriptionType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="b" type="descriptionType"></xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="movesType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="roll" nillable="false">
        <xs:complexType mixed="false">
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="simpleIntType">
              <xs:attribute name="player" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
                      <xs:maxInclusive value="4"></xs:maxInclusive>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="piece">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="nr" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="16"></xs:maxInclusive>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name="player" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
                  <xs:maxInclusive value="4"></xs:maxInclusive>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name="field" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
                  <xs:maxInclusive value="72"></xs:maxInclusive>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="simpleIntType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:maxInclusive value="6"></xs:maxInclusive>
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>


  <xs:simpleType name="playerType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive value="1"></xs:minInclusive>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="4"></xs:maxInclusive>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```